# DateTime parse C#

Tags: c#

How do I parse this date to DateTime in C#?

```
2014-09-26t1505
```

I tried the following way:

```
 DateTime pickupDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2014-09-26t1505", "t",
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"));
```

But looks like this is wrong as I am getting following error:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do like this.

```
  string dateString = "2014-09-26t1505";
  string format = "yyyy-MM-dd't'HHmm";
  CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  try {
     DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
     Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
  }
  catch (FormatException) {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
  }
```

To use ParseExact you have to actually specify the format you are using. Not sure why you just put "t". See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info and code examples.

Comment: You should probably escape `-` as well, because otherwise it will use the OS date separator character (which might be `/`).

Comment: @ThomasW., With `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` it will not.

Comment: eddit_cat, +1, Instead of using `Try-Catch` use `DateTime.TryParseExact`, That will return false if parsing is not successful.

Answer (score -1):

DateTime pickupDate = ParseExact("2014-09-26t1505", "yyyy-MM-ddtHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: You added a colon when there is no colon between hour and minute in the date string